# Rsync error: The source and destination cannot both be remote

Tags: macos, terminal, rsync, macos-high-sierra

I am able to Rsync files from my remote server to my local machine.

```
rsync -av [remote-server]:web/wp-content/uploads 

Users/[username]/Documents/workprojects/iis-tech/web/wp-content
```

Thats fine, but when I try to rsync from my local machine to my remote server I get the following error:

`The source and destination cannot both be remote.
rsync error: syntax or usage error`

The command I am running is as follows:

`rsync -av /Users/[username]/Documents/workprojects/[project-folder]/web/wp-content/themes/reactify/js/build/`

`[remote-server]:web/wp-content/themes/reactify/js/build`

I separated the command for readability.

I am using Platform.sh as the host if that makes a difference, but I don't think that is the issue.

The reason why I am confused is because my coworkers are able to run the same command successfully. 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use rsync -av /cygdrive/c.... /cygdrive/d/....
That is, replace C: with /cygdrive/c